# How to receive and process a long string sent over serial?

Tags: serial, esp8266, esp32

I want to receive about 5kb of data in Base64 format. The following code does not work. Only a few characters are received, sometimes CPU crashes.

```
String content = "";
char character;

while (Serial.available()) {
       character = Serial.read();
       content.concat(character);
}
```

I do not care about ram usage since on ESP32 there is plenty.
How can I get all the data? Example input: https://pastebin.com/wYG5AhHK

Comment: You need to signal the end of data by sending a code or a data length. `Serial.available()` may be receiving data by chunks, so it can be `false` at some moments.

Comment: I can see no logical cause, other than maybe you want to `yield()` within your while loop. You can also pre-allocate the space in your string to reduce heap mangling. `content.reserve(6000);` Better would be to not use `String` at all but use a large statically allocated character array.

Answer (score 2):

I had to read until delimiter :D

```
String receive() {
        String content = "";
        content = Serial.readStringUntil('\r');
        return content;
    }
```

Now it is fine. I will also change String to large char array.